# GetInstance not returning whole value in Long Text field from Custom Metadata

Tags: apex, custom-metadata, long-text-area

I am querying a long text area field from custom metadata using GetInstance and it is not fetching complete value.
Can somebody please tell me what is the reason?

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit to using getInstance because of which only the first 255 characters of any field in a custom metadata type record are returned.

[Link to the Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm#apex_System_CustomMetadataType_getinstance_devName)

Do a normal query to get the complete field value.
Eg: [SELECT CustomField__c FROM Custom_Setting__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'GiveTheDevName'].CustomField__c ;

Answer (score 3):

As covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm), only the first 255 characters are returned.

With the `getInstance` and `getAll` methods (to quote the documentation):

> All custom metadata is exposed in the application cache... access without repeated queries to the database.

If the full text was available, this might take up too much space in the cache, and hence this restriction.

Where the data is small you can avoid database queries and benefit from caching. If your data is large you must perform SOQL to get back the detail.

Note that we took the approach of getting the records through `getInstance` and then checking the length of the long text field; where this is 255 we then explicitly query the record through SOQL to get the whole value. There's just one edge case where the long text field content is exactly 255 characters where we will unnecessarily perform the query, but we are happy to live with this.